# Swift Physics-fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when two characters collide

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

Background on game: Basically you control a character that moves right and left and try to dodge falling blocks. There are three players spawned. One in the middle of the screen, and two exactly size.width away from the middle player on either sides.

This error only happens once in around 10 collisions with the playerRight or playerLeft or Player and falling blocks. As you can see by the screenshot below, the player does not seem to be touching the falling block when it crashes.

Error Code and Screenshots:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

[image]

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

[image]

How the game scene stopped

[image]

I'm thinking it has something to do with how I built the "infinitely" horizontal scrolling player. Basically I have three separate characters and once the middle character goes past size.width or below 0 his position on the screen is changed to the opposite side of the screen essentially making it infinite. Maybe the Player is teleported inside of a block and it gives a nil error. Not really sure but it looks like it has something to do with that. Anyway, heres the relevant code from GameScene.

```
import SpriteKit
import Foundation
import UIKit

//Collisions
 struct PhysicsCategory {
static let Enemy : UInt32 = 1
static let Player : UInt32 = 2
static let PlayerRight : UInt32 = 3
static let PlayerLeft : UInt32 = 4
static let EnemyRight : UInt32 = 5

}

var transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)



class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


//Highscore Variable
var Highscore = Int()

//Score
var Score : Int = 0
var ScoreLabel = UILabel()


//Main Character
var Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mainPlayer.png")

//Right-far character
var PlayerRight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mainPlayer.png")

//Left-far character
var PlayerLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mainPlayer.png")


//Holding vs Tapping Movement of Player
var isTouching = false

var touchXPosition:CGFloat = 0


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    //Highscore
    var HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if (HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") != nil) {
        Highscore = HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSInteger
    }
    else {
        Highscore = 0
    }




    //Collisions/Physics
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    //Background Color
    scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    //Spawn timer for enemy blocks
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemies"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    //Timer for keeping score
    var scoretimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("scoreCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    //Player coordinates
    Player.position.x = size.width * 0.5
    Player.position.y = size.width * 0.11 / 2


    //Setting Player Sizes
    Player.size.width = size.width * 0.11
    Player.size.height = size.width * 0.11
    PlayerRight.size.width = size.width * 0.11
    PlayerRight.size.height = size.width * 0.11
    PlayerLeft.size.width = size.width * 0.11
    PlayerLeft.size.height = size.width * 0.11


    //Initial position of player
    Player.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x, y: Player.position.y)
    //Initial position of far-right player
    PlayerRight.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x + size.width, y: Player.position.y)
    //Initial position of far-left player
    PlayerLeft.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x - size.width, y: Player.position.y)


    //Adding Physics/Collisions to Player
    Player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: Player.size)
    Player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    Player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
    Player.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    //Adding Physics/Collisions to PlayerRight
    PlayerRight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: PlayerRight.size)
    PlayerRight.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    PlayerRight.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.PlayerRight
    PlayerRight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
    PlayerRight.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    //Adding Physics/Collisions to PlayerLeft
    PlayerLeft.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: PlayerRight.size)
    PlayerLeft.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    PlayerLeft.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.PlayerLeft
    PlayerLeft.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
    PlayerLeft.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    //Making Players visible
    self.addChild(Player)
    self.addChild(PlayerRight)
    self.addChild(PlayerLeft)

    //Making Score Visible
    ScoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
    ScoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
    ScoreLabel.font = UIFont(name: ScoreLabel.font.fontName, size:20)
    ScoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view?.addSubview(ScoreLabel)
}

func scoreCounter() {
    //Setting score
    Score += 1
    ScoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
}


func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    //Checking for Player to enemy collisions
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Player)){
        CollisionWithEnemy(firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode, Player: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) {
        CollisionWithEnemy2(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Enemy: secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode)
    }
    //Checking for PlayerRight to enemy collisions
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PlayerRight)){
        CollisionWithEnemy(firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode, Player: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PlayerRight) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) {
        CollisionWithEnemy2(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Enemy: secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode)
    }
    //Checking for PlayerLeft to enemy collisions
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PlayerLeft)){
        CollisionWithEnemy(firstBody.node as! SKShapeNode, Player: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }
    else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PlayerLeft) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) {
        CollisionWithEnemy2(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Enemy: secondBody.node as! SKShapeNode)
    }

}

func CollisionWithEnemy(Enemy: SKShapeNode, Player: SKSpriteNode) {

    //Highscore
    var ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
    ScoreDefault.synchronize()


    if (Score > Highscore) {
        var HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        HighscoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Highscore")
    }

    //var gameOver:SKScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
    //ScoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    Enemy.removeFromParent()
    //Player.removeFromParent()
    //self.view?.presentScene(gameOver, transition: transition)


}

func CollisionWithEnemy2(Player: SKSpriteNode, Enemy: SKShapeNode) {

    //Highscore
    var ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
    ScoreDefault.synchronize()

    if (Score > Highscore) {
        var HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        HighscoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Highscore")
    }

    //var gameOver:SKScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
    //ScoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    Enemy.removeFromParent()
    //Player.removeFromParent()
    //self.view?.presentScene(gameOver, transition: transition)
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    isTouching = true

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        touchXPosition = location.x

    }

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    isTouching = false
}


func spawnEnemies() {
    //Randomizing width of blocks
    var blockWidth = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.width / 3)) + UInt32(size.width / 5))

    //Min and Max position of blocks
    var minPosition : UInt32 = UInt32(blockWidth / 2)
    var maxPosition : UInt32 = UInt32(size.width - CGFloat(blockWidth / 2))

    //Randomizing Block Position
    var blockXPosition = arc4random_uniform(maxPosition - minPosition) + minPosition

    //Making Blocks
    var Enemy = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: blockWidth, height: 5))
    Enemy.position = CGPointMake (CGFloat(blockXPosition),  CGFloat(size.height+50))

    //Coloring Blocks
    Enemy.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    //Moving Blocks
    let action = SKAction.moveToY(-50, duration: 2.5)

    //Removing blocks once off screen
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    //Running the above actions
    Enemy.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))


    //Physics/Collisions
    Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize (width: blockWidth, height: 1))
    Enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
    Enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Enemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    //Adding enemy to scene
    self.addChild(Enemy)

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    var offsetLeft = 0 - (Player.position.x - 25)


    Player.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x, y: Player.position.y)

    PlayerRight.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x + size.width, y: Player.position.y)

    PlayerLeft.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x - size.width, y: Player.position.y)

    if isTouching {
        if touchXPosition > self.size.width / 2 {
            // move character to the right.
            Player.position.x += 10

        }
        if touchXPosition < self.size.width / 2 {
            // move character to the left.
            Player.position.x -= 10

        }
    }


    if Player.position.x < 0 {
        Player.position.x = size.width
    }
    if Player.position.x > size.width {
        Player.position.x = 0
    }
}
}
```

Everything is commented fairly well but if you have any questions about whats what let me know. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't paste screen shots of code, error messages, etc. Paste _code_. Paste _error messages_. Explain the problem. Don't make people deal with images of code.

Comment: My bad man I'll update it accordingly.

Comment: Please do not "delete" your question - if you find a solution you can answer your own question

Answer (score 2):

```
static let PlayerRight : UInt32 = 3 //00000000000000000000000000000100
static let PlayerLeft : UInt32 = 4  //00000000000000000000000000001000
static let EnemyRight : UInt32 = 5  //00000000000000000000000000010000
```

Do you *really* believe that 3 is binary `100` and that 4 is binary `1000` (and so on)? Because if you do, and if you need that to be true, you are going to be in huge trouble later if you try to use these values as actual bitmasks.

Comment: I've got no idea honestly but it doesn't matter to my code I don't think. I was watching a tutorial and that is what the guy said they were so sorry if they aren't. I'll fix the code although it doesn't really matter because they are comments. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: @Darkstar I guess you missed `1 << 3` `1 << 4` etc. then it would be (almost) correct

Comment: Yes, understanding the code you copy together doesn't matter. Just permute it around until it "sort of works", when we will do the rest. And if not, just publish it on the store. :)